# jQuery's .val() returns different values for input elements with placeholder text in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, firefox

Given the following HTML, I'm seeing different values being returned in Firefox and Chrome when using the latest jQuery:

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Type Here">
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Type Here">
```

jQuery:

```
jQuery("#name").val();  // Returns "Type Here" in Chrome, blank in Firefox
jQuery("#email").val(); // Returns "Type Here" in Chrome, blank in Firefox
```

In my opinion the above should return a blank string, since "Type here" is only placeholder text.

Why the difference here?

Comment: I suspect you have code somewhere that's putting the placeholder into the value, maybe left over from before you added the placeholder attributes. That was the old way to do it.

Comment: I can't reproduce it here: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/uvz28eyg/

Comment: Another thought: maybe you have a Chrome extension that's doing it. Try turning off extensions and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Or may be you are using some poly-fill to have placeholder feature for outdated browsers..Which adds value from placeholder attribute and removes it `onfocus`

Comment: are you using html5 ?

Comment: @Barmar Absolutely correct. Legacy code was doing that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @BarMar commented, I found some ugly old code that was taking the placeholder attribute and making it an actual value:

```
/* Placeholder Fix */
$('[placeholder]').focus(function() {
    var input = $(this);
    if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
        input.val('');
        input.removeClass('placeholder');
    }
}).blur(function() {
    var input = $(this);
    if (input.val() == '' || input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
        input.addClass('placeholder');
        input.val(input.attr('placeholder'));
    }
}).blur().parents('form').submit(function() {
    $(this).find('[placeholder]').each(function() {
        var input = $(this);
        if (input.val() == input.attr('placeholder')) {
            input.val('');
        }
    })
});
```

Removed this and it's fine now. Thanks.